# Swift 3 Unit Testing - Linker fails when using import @testable

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, cocoa, linker

I'm currently trying to write unit tests (**NOT** UI Tests) for my (macOS) Xcode project. I have created a new Unit Test target which creates a blank unit test file for me.

This complies and links fine, but there are no tests.

As soon as I add the line `@testable import Pilot`, where `Pilot` is the name of my App Target, and I try to compile and run, it fails with this message:

`Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I've tried everything I can find, but nothing seems to be working. The other posts I have read on here deal with this problem in UI Tests, but that is because you cannot use `@testable` in UI Tests. You are supposed to be able to use it in Unit Tests, but I can't figure out why this is not working.

Does anyone have any insight?

If it helps, my project is located at: https://github.com/RohanNagar/pilot-osx

Here is the full `PilotTests.swift` file:

```
import XCTest

@testable import Pilot

class PilotTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() {
        // This is an example of a performance test case.
        self.measure {
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your CocoaPods frameworks not included in the Test targets. It will throw this error.

I made sure running a pod install, but still it failed.

So 'pod deintegrate Yourproject.xcodeproj' and reinstall (pod install), clears the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The import fails because the project fails to link together. I downloaded it and I get the following error trying to run it:

```
Showing Recent Issues
ld: framework not found Realm for architecture x86_64
```

Try to clean your build folder, or download the project to a new folder, and fix this issue... after that you'll be able to compile and @testable import Pilot.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Turns out none of my CocoaPods frameworks were being included in the Test targets (was not an issue prior to CocoaPods 1.0.0), so fixing that solved my linking problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Set Host Application to your Project Target.
Also, check the Allow testing Host Application APIs is turned on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your test target
2. Select Build Phases
3. In the Framework Search Paths, add this
   `"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/"` with `recursive` option